# ActiveX Property Persistance

Tags: mfc, activex

I have a question about an ActiveX Control I am developing.  I have hashed my way through most problems but I am stuck at a real road block.  This ActiveX is being imorted into other software so I have to have a good implementation of the Property Pages.  I have managed to get some persistant properties working with one issue.  When I make a change in the property page it is updated and persists as long as the application that is development app that is using it is open but it reverts back when I reload the app.  I have narrowed this down to the fact that the development app doesnt realize the ActiveX has changed and therfore doesnt save.  If i make a unrelated change and save the program all is good and the values persist as expected.  I have tried everything and cant seem t get the application that imports my ActiveX to realize when it has changed via the property page.  I am wondering if anyone has some work arounds for this type of problem.  It seems to me if I could force the DoPropExchange() it would work but I dont know how to call this explicitly.

Thanks in advance
Matt

Thanks for the input.  I did have the SetModifiedFlag() but it wasnt working.  After poking at it I solved that problem but now I am redirecting my question.  I had removed the property above in question from the idl files dispinterface in order to prevent the application that loads the activex from displaying the property in its "Connection List"(3rd party application specific").  It appears that the app loads all the interface into this list but this is not good as some properties should be persistant and only modifiable through the proppages.  I tried all the flags like hidden and local but still were displayed in the list.  When I removed it from the dispinterface it was how I wanted it but would not signal the IsModified.  My new question is in there another way to define properties for an instance like this or is it possible to have a secondary interface(I have not tested if the application would see this interface because I am not sure how I would go about defining this inteface)or to have a property only between the proppage and control. Or is there another way to signal the dirty.  The OnMemberVariable of the control was properly executing I know from testing it just seems SetModifiedFlag() doesnt do anything if the property is not in the dispinterface

Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your control as "modified", so that its host could detect it and re-save persistent properties. In this case `IPersistXxx::IsDirty` implemented by your control would indicate dirty state.

MFC based control has [`COleControl::SetModifiedFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25xfstyh.aspx) for this purpose:

> Call this function whenever a change occurs that would affect your control's persistent state. For example, if the value of a persistent property changes, call this function with bModified TRUE.

Update: To hide a property from property browser you can use [`nonbrowsable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute.

> Use the [nonbrowsable] attribute to tag an interface or dispinterface member that should not be displayed in a properties browser.